# How to display custom category attribute in category form magento2?

Tags: magento2, module, category-attribute, dynamic

I have created custom category attribute in Magento 2.1.X version. Attribute created successfully in the database.

I know display category attribute using UI-component **'category_form.xml'** but that would be static we have to write each and everything in XML.

I want to display dynamic category attributes in category form could anyone suggest me how we can achieve this?

Also found this issue is reported in github also https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5942 .

Comment: I have the same problem, anyone has a solution ? Thanks !